# How to fetch Twitter Username and Profile Photo using the Twit NPM Package

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am making use of the `twit` npm pacakge as below to get the Authenticated Twitter Username and Profile Image amongst other information.

```
        const Twit = require('twit');

        let T = new Twit({
            consumer_key: 'xxx',
            consumer_secret: 'xxx',
            access_token: 'xxx',
            access_token_secret: 'xxx',
            timeout_ms: 60 * 1000,  
            strictSSL: true,
        });
        T.get('users/show.json', { screen_name: `${usernameFromAbove}`}, function (err, data, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(`User Fetch Error`);
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Unfortunately the response I keep getting is this:

```
2021-09-23T23:38:55.659299+00:00 app[web.1]:   errors: [ { message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist', code: 34 } ]
```

Am I calling the wrong endpoint? I'm currently confused?

Any insight to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint is `'users/show'` not `'users/show.json'`.

Comment: Yea, I figured it out  as such. Thanks all the same for your input.